# Pass object from Javascript to C++/CX based on C++/CX interface - Windows Runtime Components

Tags: javascript, windows, runtime, components, c++-cx

I'm new to Windows Runtime Component, and have been trying to figure out how to achieve the following.

The C++ interface I want to extend from in Javascript.

```
namespace MySDK {
    public interface class LoggerPlugin
    {
    public:
        virtual void Log (Platform::String^ Tag, Platform::String^ Messsage);
    };
}
```

The C++

```
namespace MySDK {
    public ref class Logger sealed : public Platform::Object
    {
    public:
        static Logger^ GetInstance ();
        void SetPlugin (LoggerPlugin^ Plugin);
    };
}
```

What I tried, may seem silly, but I have no idea how to achieve it.

```
var plugin = {
     log: function(tag, message) {
          console.log(tag + ':' + message);
     }
};

MySdk.Logger.getInstance().setPlugin(plugin);
```

The error that I get is

```
JavaScript runtime error: Type mismatch
```

I couldn't find any documentation or examples on how to achieve this, will appreciate if anyone could provide me an example of how this can be done.

Comment: This is not C++. Maybe C++/CX or C++/CLI?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot implement WinRT interfaces. If you want to have a JavaScript implementation of your plugin, then you will need to build a concrete type that raises events (that JavaScript can subscribe to) rather than defining virtual methods (that C++ or C# could implement).